# How to put margin on Action Bar icon when SearchView is open?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout

Well, I have an Action Bar icon that only shows when my SearchView is open:

Before opening SearchView:

[image]

After opening SearchView:

[image]

But that "settings" icon is without the standard Right-Margin... How can I put some margin on it? I've searched for this and found nothing...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where is that gear icon coming from?

Comment: It's coming from my action bar menu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I've changed from `android.widget.SearchView` to `android.support.v7.widget.SearchView` and now it's working fine (: